# Copy column of a row to another row where condition and then delete it

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table where I'm trying to get rid of some rows. 
All these rows contain a letter where they should only contain a numeric value.

Example:[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDaoX.png)

So I pretty much want to copy the column grade_percent of column 1 to 'class_rank' of column 2 and then delete column 1.
The thing is that I have about 9k rows and there are different marking_period_ids

I was thinking of doing something like

```
UPDATE table SET class_rank=(SELECT exam from table WHERE marking_period_id)
```

but that's where I get lost as I have no idea how to make this repetitive straight from a postgresql query

Comment: Please take a few moments and include sample data directly in your question as _text_.  Also, are you using Postgres or MySQL?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Can you just briefly explain what's your schema like? I have a couple of questions. 1) How is marking period related to the operation that you wish to do? 2) You say that you want to copy `grade_percent` to `class_rank` and your UPDATE query tries to copy `exam` into `class_rank` 3) Are class_rank and grade_percent columns of the same type?

Comment: Where's the `exam` column from in your screenshot?

Comment: Do you need to do this in one query?  Based on your description (and I don't know why you need to get `marking_period_ids` involved), you can just do `UPDATE "table" SET class_rank=grade_percent` and then `ALTER TABLE "table" DROP COLUMN grade_percent`.  BTW, naming your table `table` is not a good practice (but I assume you are just calling it `table` for the same of example here)